# Why is this closed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, closed-questions, specific-question

Why is this closed?

[The fall of the Communist bloc as seen from the eastern side](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/1972/)

It's not really subjective.

And it can't possibly be argued to be off-topic for SFF: **sociopolitical fiction about the future is a VERY VERY large subset of - especially, Eastern Block - SciFi** (See Strugatsky, Bulychyov, etc...). As in, there are more "SciFi" works that fit the topic Gilles asked about than non-SciFi works.

Comment: I can't speak to reasoning, but in terms of process, this is what happened.  [This answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/26507/1027) bumped the question.  It received a couple of close votes.  Then it [went to](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/close/4338) the Close Votes queue, where it picked up it's last few VTCs.  I vaguely recall seeing it when it was bumped, but didn't think it needed closing at the time.  The question is from the super-early days of the site, so I'm not surprised that ~2 years later it was deemed close-worthy.

Comment: I don't remember seeing it, but I would not have VTCed if I saw this come up in the queue. While any correct answer would hardly be concise, I still feel that it can be objectively and conclusively answered (and definitely on topic). I very much believe that old questions shouldn't be closed without very good reasons... it would have been eliminated as spam/garbage early on if it were that sort of post. Too bad it can't display a warning that advises caution on closing old questions when someone attempts VTC.

Comment: @Keen - that explains the mechanics but not the justification. I don't see any reason why it should be closed. It is in no way, shape or form "not constructive", althogh admittedly it doesn't fit the usual "**no analysis or synthesis effort required**" mold more typical to the trivial questions this site is teeming with. I have a feeling that was what Gilles was referring to when he said the site was not living up to its potential as per his hopes, and I fully agree.

Comment: If I had to hazard a guess, I'd say because answering requires one of two things: (1) a recommendation of analyses to look into, or (2) analysis itself, known as *discussion*.  It doesn't seem to be the best fit for SE.  The comments also indicate that people feel that it's off-topic, being more about geopolitics and history than SF, among other things.

Comment: Voted to reopen. Good SF is very often political in at least some way. While there may be other reasons why people VTCed, I want to hear those reasons before accepting the closing. If it was closed because it was deemed too ideological, I disagree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see absolutely no reason why this question should be closed.  It is on topic (it focuses on science fiction works), constructive (looks for a general description of writing trends on a specific topic), not too localized (specific topic, specific geographic region) and not a duplicate.

I find the question interesting, as did quite a few other people, judging from the votes.

My suspicion is that it received close votes because elements of the question, and potentially some answers, are fairly abstract.  I don't feel that those are reasons to vote to close, however, and I'm glad to see that the question has been re-opened.

It probably didn't help that one of the answers includes a lot of completely off-topic and irrelevant socio-political commentary that should probably be edited out of the answer entirely.

Comment: I suspect it was also a victim of the initial rush when the review queues were new.